# If $X \subset F$ and $F$ is closed then $\bar{X} \subset F$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

> Prove that if $X \subset F$ and $F$ is closed then $\bar{X} \subset F$.

**Remark:** This is from a first course in real analysis so all sets are implicitly assumed to be subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and all proofs should be rather elementary. Also I don't know if this is standard notation but $\bar{X}$ is the notation my textbook uses for the closure of $X$.

**Attempt:**

$X \subset F \Rightarrow$ all elements of $X$ are in $F$.

$F$ is closed $\iff F = \bar{F} \iff$ all adherent points of $F$ are in $F$.

Suppose that there exist elements of $\bar{X}$ that are not in $F$. Then, there exist points which are adherent to $X$ but are not adherent to $F$, which contradicts the hypothesis that $F$ is closed. Therefore we must have that $\bar{X} \subset F$.

Comment: Prove that  $X\subset F\implies \overline X\subset \overline F$ for any $X,F.$ Then  $X\subset F=\overline F\implies  \overline X\subset \overline F=F.$

Comment: Can you remove the contradiction argument and make a direct argument?

Comment: @TedShifrin I’m not sure how. I’m not sure if my proof is correct either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $X \subset F$. Then, if $x$ is adherent to $X$, every open set containing $x$ intercepts $X$ at some point, so this implies that every open set containing $x$ intercept $F$ at some point, and we conclude $\bar{X}\subset\bar{F}$. Thus, we have $\bar{X}\subset \bar{F} = F$.

Comment: I don’t see how your arguments imply “and we conclude...”

Comment: I took an element of $\bar{X}$ and concluded that it is also an element of $\bar{F}$, so $\bar{X}\subset \bar{F}$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the closure of $X$ is the intersection of all closed subsets containing $X$.

Answer (score 1):

$A\subseteq F$ $\implies$ $cl(A)\subseteq cl(F)$. But $F$ is closed, meaning $cl(F)=F$.

Comment: Can you tell if my proof in particular is right?